# Failed to remove labels from force directed graph

Tags: svg, d3.js

I try to add some labels in my force directed graph but for some reason that i dont know i cant "remove" them when i try to expand / shrink my nodeset.

my code for the labels is the following:

```
var labels = labelg.selectAll('text .textlabel').data(data.links);
    labels.exit().remove();
    labels.enter().append('text')
        .attr('class','textlabel')
        .attr("x", function(d) {return d.size ? (d.source.group_data.x + d.target.group_data.x) / 2 : (d.source.x + d.target.x)/2 ;})
        .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.size ? (d.source.group_data.y + d.target.group_data.y) / 2 : (d.source.y + d.target.y))/2 ; })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) {return d.reason;});
```

and in my "tick" function i positioned as follows

```
force.on("tick", function() {
//... node & link stuff ...

  labels
      .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.size ? (d.source.group_data.x + d.target.group_data.x) / 2 : (d.source.x + d.target.x)/2) ; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.size ? (d.source.group_data.y + d.target.group_data.y) / 2 : (d.source.y + d.target.y))/2 ; });

});
```

And now, if i click on a node, the group expand and shows the labels between the nodes. But if i expand the second group and/or contract the first one, the labels are not be removed.

for a better understanding of my problem i make a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NVmf5/

Does someone may help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem here is that you're setting up the labels with `data.links` - so you always have all the labels for all your links in the SVG. The only reason you don't see them is that, if their group isn't expanded, the `x` and `y` attributes are set to `NaN`, so the labels are off-screen. Once you expand, the `x` and `y` values are set; contracting stop them from updating, but the `data.links` array doesn't change, so nothing is removed.

Comment: this it is :-/ Thanks for the hint!